# windows command line web content filter like mitmproxy

Tags: filter, proxy, man-in-the-middle

I would like to block websites like Facebook, Twitter etc.. I am looking for a simple little command line tool (windows XP 7) that goes like:

filter.exe -list.txt

///------------list.txt------------
*.facebook.*
*.twitter.*

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If the local user does not have administrator privileges, just edit the host file to point those domains to other locations. You can write a batch file to edit the host file.